# Selenium Web Driver code with Java not navigating the website

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, internet-explorer, webdriver

I have below code in eclipse. I am trying to execute it in Chrome. It works fine till clicking on ID #divpaxinfo, but it does not add number of adults. On IE, It does nothing. It just opens the webpage and stops navigating. I have been struggling to know what is the issue, but nothing seems wrong at my end. What could be the issue with?

```
package testProject2;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.By.ById;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\bk0107\\Documents\\QA\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();



        driver.get("http://spicejet.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).click();

           /*int i=1;

        while(i<5)

        {

        driver.findElement(By.id("hrefIncAdt")).click();//4 times

        i++;

        }*/

           System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());

        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)

        {

        driver.findElement(By.id("hrefIncAdt")).click();

        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnclosepaxoption")).click();

        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please try provided answer and let me know if you have any concerns?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that ChromeDriver is really really fast.  As a result it's trying to click on an element before Chrome has finished rendering it and the element is not yet clickable.

The correct solution is to use an explicit wait to wait until the element is clickable, then click on it.  You should never mix implicit and explicit waits, so once you have decided to use explicit waits stick with them (they are best practice).

I've added a full set of refactored code, you really only need to add the WebDriver wait and tweak your loop though.

```
driver.get("http://spicejet.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).click();

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 50);
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("hrefIncAdt"))).click();
}

driver.findElement(By.id("btnclosepaxoption")).click();

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());
```

This explicitly waits for the element that you want to click on to be clickable before you click on it, this is a better check than visibility because an element can be visible, but not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Implicit wait and browser maximize code Just after creating instance of driver as follows :**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

**Suggestion :** Add some wait(implicit/fluent) in script for proper execution

**Your Program with improvements :**

```
package practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\win\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://spicejet.com");

        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("divpaxinfo")));
        element.click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());

        WebElement element1 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("hrefIncAdt")));
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
            element1.click();
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnclosepaxoption")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't added implicit or fluent waits in your code example, you have just used Thread.sleep which is a horrible coding practice.  Also maximising the window is going to do nothing useful at all.

Comment: @Ardesco : Removed Thread.sleep... Tested the code it is working fine

Comment: You really don't want to mix implicit and explicit waits either, you are in the realms of undefined functionality.  Different driver binaries and different versions of driver binaries work in slightly different ways when mixing these types of wait.